# Creating space vacuum

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i'm trying to make a mini-game on my friends server. I am making it in "space" on a space station. I'm trying to design it so whenever a hole is made in the space station all players will get sucked out and die. I don't think this is possible but if it is can you try to find an answer in 1.7.10, if not just give me an answer for 1.8.

Comment: Teleport to the void?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Sorry. Ya your're right.

Comment: @gamer103 If you've figured it out, you could answer the question yourself so that others will know how to do this.

Comment: Oh wait. Actually i need an answer again becuase when i wrote i figured it out i had but i didn't have time to test it and when i did test it it didn't give me the answer i wanted.

Comment: @Alt-F4 I am planning to tp them to the void but I need the commands to realize that a block is missing in the wall then I can tp them to the void

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of your comments, saying that you'll teleport them to the void, you could use the command `testforblocks` which compares 2 3-dimensional areas and tests if they're the same. If your machine notices that the blocks are not identical, it will teleport them. Testing for if there's a hole may be a bit more tedious, and you'll need multiple `testforblock` commands testing for each wall.

Comment: Do this work in 1.7.10?

Comment: I believe it doesn't, though I'm not sure. Testforblocks may have been added in 1.8